# Rails: `before_save` interfere with `save?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-save

I'm using seed.rb to start my app.

```
#seeds.rb, create categories and see if they are saved or not 
categories = Category.create([{name:'name1'},{name:'name2'}, {name: 'name3'} ])
if categories.all?(&:save)
  puts "categories saved"
else
  puts "categories saved failed"
end
```

In Category Model, I have:
`before_Save :get_external_resources`
so I can use nokogiri to fetch something outsite my site

The problem is that when I run `rake db:seed`, the categories will be saved twice.
I tried turn off the `before_save`, and it only save once. So I guess that`all?(&:save)` and `before_save` have saved this array twice, seperately.

How can I avoid the extra saving? 
I need to do something before the object get saved and I want to know wheather these objects are saved or not when seeding. How about `after_create`? I think I'll need to add `self.save` in methods and may have some validation problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, .create and .save will both save the record, and each will trigger the before_save callback. (if you don't want .create to save, change to `Category.new`

If you'd like `get_external_resources` to only execute once, you could do one of:

1. change it to `before_save :get_external_resources, on: :create`
2. change the `get_external_resources` to only run once

Comment: `on: :create` works. But I still didn't get the point. It seems like that`.create` triggers a save, and `before_save :get_external_resources` triggers another?